# Adding numbers of date to single digit

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to add numbers in a date to a single digit number. For example, 28-July-1974
So if I add it as 2+8+7+1+9+7+4 = 38 as two digits total. I need it as 2 (3+8). What formula will help?

Comment: Do you need it finally as a string in the form: " 3+ 8" ?

Comment: I need final result in single digit. So here it's 38. If we add 3 + 8 = 11 (still double digit). So further 1 + 1 = 2. So I want 2 and not 38  or 11.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the MOD of `9` to get the sum to the single digit:

```
=MOD(--TEXT(A1,"ddmmyyyy")-1,9)+1
```

[image]

Comment: For additional reading, see [Casting Out Nines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casting_out_nines).

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following User Defined Function:

```
Public Function numerify(rng As Range) As Integer
    Dim s As String, L As Long, i As Long, zum As Long
    Dim inpt As String
    
    inpt = rng.Text
    arr = Split(inpt, "-")
    mnth = Month(DateValue(arr(1) & "/1/2000"))
    s = arr(0) & CStr(mnth) & arr(2)
    
    While Len(s) > 1
        MsgBox s
        L = Len(s)
        zum = 0
        For i = 1 To L
            zum = zum + CLng(Mid(s, i, 1))
        Next i
        s = CStr(zum)
    Wend
    
    numerify = CInt(s)
End Function
```

It will repeated add digits until a single digit is achieved:

[image]